# How to parse JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1, json.net

I have a weird JSON string which needs to be parsed in C#. How do I do it. I tried parsing it as a `Dictionary` but it failed. Can I somehow create a hashmap?

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
```

The JSON string is [here](https://gist.github.com/maskaravivek/33aa0d6556bbb9ecb77a).

I am getting this data using a API. This is the error that i am receiving.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. `ICollection`, `IList`) like `List<T>` that can be deserialized from a JSON array. `JsonArrayAttribute` can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: the link does not work

Comment: This question is utterly pointless and highlights why we shouldn't be pointing to 3rd party resources.

Comment: What kind of failure are you getting?

Comment: link updated. Should i add the whole JSON string over here?

Comment: If this is a parameter in a webmethod then my advice is to make the paramter Dictionary<string, string>, then the build-in deserializer will do the job.

Comment: @VivekMaskara : Yes. You should add everything that is essential to getting an answer to your question in the body of the question. That way, its lifetime isn't affected by the lifetime of the external content. If there's too much to post, you might want to consider a smaller sample that demonstrates the problem more concisely. Just this excercise alone can help greatly in your own understanding of the problem.

Comment: You don't deserialize into a dictionary, but into an object with matching named fields (of basic types or arrays or more objects with same rules). You can also use it as a dynamic type if you don't want to create a class for this.

Comment: @YoryeNathan. Actually, you'd want to deserialize to a collection of such objects. OPs JSON is an `Array`.

Comment: @spender That is true. An array of objects with appropriate fields, etc. But he's thinking it goes into a dictionary which is the main fault here.

Comment: FYI: If you want to create a class for the JSON then copy the JSON to clipboard and go to Visual Studio menu `Edit>Paste Special>Paste JSON As Classes`. (This only works in .NET 4.5 or later I think - or is it 4?)

Comment: @Ulric That's very cool, thanks :)

Comment: @Yorye It sometimes gets the property types wrong (as it has to guess from the data provided) but, other than that, it is a great time-saver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see is that the JSON you have pointed out has a regular structure and you should create a wrapping model for it see example below or play with it in https://dotnetfiddle.net/TGWTNC.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maskaravivek/33aa0d6556bbb9ecb77a/raw/b815daa55719a754eef5117321e2c0c5621c6a18/gistfile1.txt");
        var notifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Notification[]>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(notifications.Count());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

//adjust the data types according to your needs
public class Notification
{
    public string notificationId { get; set; }
    public string readFlag { get; set; }
    public string importantFlag { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string folder { get; set; }
    public string creationTime { get; set; }
    public string notificationCount { get; set; }
    public string jobId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> recruitersMap { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> jobsMap { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The shape of your JSON data won't fit in a `Dictionary<string,string>` because at its top level, it's not a dictionary. It's an array of objects.

You need to write a custom type (`class`) that matches the shape of your data, then deserialize to a collection of such types.

So, broadly speaking (with untested code...)

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string notificationId{ get; set; }
    //etc
    public Dictionary<string,string> recruitersMap{ get; set; }
    //etc
}
```

then

```
JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<SomeType>>(someJson)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because your JSON does not represent a `Dictionary<string, string>`. `recruitersMap` and `jobsMap` are both nested `object`s or collections, not `string`s.

you could create a POCO class

```
    public class ApiEndPoint // you will find a better name, I'm sure
    {
        public string notificationId { get; set; }
        public string readFlag { get; set; }
        public string importantFlag { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string folder { get; set; }
        public DateTime creationTime { get; set; }
        public int notificationCount { get; set; }
        public string jobId { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> recruitersMap { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> jobsMap { get; set; }
    }
```

and deserialize the json into a object of that class like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ApiEndPoint>>(yourJsonString);
```